# What weapon talent tree combination provides the highest dps with the greatsword?

Tags: new-world

I've been playing with the new greatsword weapon for a while now, but I'm not a numbers kind of person and am having a hard time determining what the best dps talent combination is, so here I am.

What weapon talent tree combination provides the highest dps with the greatsword?